# A book complied of photographs, supplied as tiffs, but would pdfs be better?

Tags: print-design, pdf, tiff

I'm design a book complied of photographs, supplied as tiffs, but would pdfs be better? I've used tiff in full Colour print magazines before but it has been suggested I use them as PDFs. Is this correct for original photos too?

Answer (score 3):

No, no...

Pdf should be the output of the composed page.

Leave your photos as tif, then you make the design let us say in InDesign, you put the page number, the measurements of the page, some text, etc. And then the output should be as pdf, with the proper settings.

They are not that interchangable. They are used in diferent steps of the process.

Answer (score 2):

Once documents have been created, a determination needs to be made as to how those images will be stored. In general, the two primary choices are to store the files in either PDF format or TIFF format. While there are a few technical differences between the two, it is more of a preference choice than a technology choice.

Here you are some properties for both format:

1. The main advantage the Adobe claims for PDF is its portability. It doesn't matter what operating system you have or what type of hardware you have, in addition,
2. recently nearly all the print shops now going digital and are depending on PDF as it can store some additional information that cant be stored in TIF, like vector information and color profiles and text over image capability for searching.
3. PDF file format can be secured with various levels of security modes and support digital signature.
4. PDF could be optimized for fast web viewing and distribution.
5. research and web implementation are focusing more over PDF file format more that the TIFF file format.
6. for compatibility with the OS's, portability, file size and compression modes both are the same.

For my opinion the depending over PDF are growing more that ever from schools universities and governmental offices, and for more that 20 years PDF file format proof -in my opinion- is the best man made digital creation after the creation of PC's and till now you can open PDF that are that old.

You have to decide which file format you want to use according on some questions you have to answer first, for example: your document is is a text base document or a graphics base one? do you intend to distribute it over the Internet? do you need to search within it? do you need to secure your document?

After your answers, you probably be able to choose the best file format for your project.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Rafael's answer, make sure that the TIFFs are in RGB before you place them in the layout software. For prepress use, eciRGB v2 would be the recommended profile.

When preparing the output, you would ask the printshop which PDF/x standard they support. Common is PDF/x-1a and PDF/X-4 (in the latter, you don't even need to have the layout software to convert the images to CMYK; you can keep them in RGB.